# Performing an Interval Regression in R

Tags: r

I am trying to run an interval regression, where my dependent variable, *y* is made up of 14 intervals, representing incomes. I have 5000 observations. I have six independent variables I am trying to use to predict my *y*.

I am trying to follow the steps performed here:

http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~pesta/NMFM404/interval.html#References

So, I actually have *y* at its exact values, but am trying to learn how to do an interval regression from this. So, first I convert *y* into an interval.

`Income[Income < 10000] <- 1
Income[Income > 10000 & Income < 20001] <- 2
Income[Income > 20000 & Income < 30001] <- 3
...
Income[Income > 300000] <- 14`

Okay, fine. From the above link, I should actually convert it to correspond to each lower bound of the interval, and each upper bound. I have to imagine that isn't the only way, but for now, I am following those directions.

```
 lIncome <- rep(0,5000)#lower income bound
uIncome <- rep(0,5000)#upper income bound

for (i in 1:5000){
    if(Income[i] == 1){
        lIncome[i] = 0
        uIncome[i] = 10000      
    }
    if(Income[i] == 2){
        lIncome[i] = 10001
        uIncome[i] = 20000      
    }
    ...
    if(Income[i] == 14){
        lIncome[i] = 300001
        uIncome[i] = Inf    
    }
}
```

So now I have columns lIncome and uIncome which correspond to the levels of income. I am fine for this part. Perhaps it is problematic my last interval goes to infinity; but even if I just cap it at 500000 I still get errors.

The instructions next say to incorporate the Surv() function.

So, I perform:

```
TEST <- Surv(lIncome, uIncome, event = rep(3,5000))
```

However, my errors start now. I get:

```
    Warning message:
In Surv(lIncome, uIncome, event = rep(3, 5000)) :
  Invalid status value, converted to NA
```

If I try

```
TEST <- Surv(lIncome, uIncome, event = rep(2,5000))
```

it works, but then:

```
m <- survreg(TEST ~ Age + AgeSq + ... , dist="gaussian")
```

gives:

```
    Error in survreg(TEST ~ Age + AgeSq + NoDegree, dist = "gaussian") : 
  Invalid survival type
```

First of all, I am not sure why changing the 3 -> 2 makes it work. Even if I change the Inf value to 500000 (or any appropriate number) having it equal to 2 (or any number) does not resolve the issue.

Second, when I can get past that part, the fact that survreg is failing is leaving me puzzled.

Right now, my approach is to play around with my intervals, to see if I can get it to work somehow, then go from there. I am also looking closer at all the documentation for ?Surv and ?survreg

Any help is very appreciated though, thank you.

Comment: In the meantime, I am going to try this for the package intreg (See here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/intReg/intReg.pdf )

Comment: Long problem description but no actual data.

Comment: Sorry, how should I attach the data?

Comment: Either a link to a downloadable site or using dput to create a text "image" that you put into a code block in your question.

Comment: Okay, thank you. 

I got results from the link I listed using the intReg package, and they seem good, so I may not need help for this anymore though.

Although I will attempt to also perform a multinomial probit regression, I need to try that on my own more first. 

I appreciate the interest in helping me though.